# ListView in Scrolling Activity displays Only A Single Item

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am using a Scrolling Activity, that comes with Android Studio 1.4 In this I have an ImageView and a ListView. The xml for this layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.viv.droidchef.EachRec"
    tools:showIn="@layout/each_rec">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/recPixx"/>
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ingredients_list"></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The problem I am facing is that in my ListView only the first item is shown. Here's my code for the ListView

```
String ingredients = new String[]{
                    " Boneless Chicken                    - 300 g",
                    "Ginger garlic paste                   - 2 tsp",
                    " Kashmiri red chilly pwd              - ¾ tsp",
                    "Lemon juice                           - 1 tsp",
                    "Salt to taste                                ",
                    "Cooking oil                     - 3 to 4 tbsp",
                    "Gram / besan flour (kadalai maavu    - 2 tbsp",
                    "Yoghurt                               - 1 cup",
                    "Kashmiri red chilly pwd               - 1 tsp",
                    " Ginger garlic paste                  - 1 tsp",
                    "Turmeric pwd                          - ¼ tsp",
                    "Garam masala pwd                      - ½ tsp",
                    "Salt as required                             "
            };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, ingredients);
        ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ingredients_list);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
lv.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                        v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                        break;
                }

                // Handle ListView touch events.
                v.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

I've used choice mode multiple, because I want a checklist. I'm using the setOnTouchListener because I already have a NestedScrollView in my Layout. I found this on another SO post.
If I put the height of the dp fixed it seems to work, but that doesn't help as 
it will look different on each screen size.
Is there a way to fix the issue I am facing and get all items on the list without using Dp?

Comment: Having a scrolling view (ListView) inside another scrolling view isn't a good idea. Instead, maybe you can make that imageview a header to your Listview

Comment: for which view are you trying to set dimensions in **dp**

Comment: So, this method won't work out?

Comment: Pankaj if I set the listviews dp as a fixed value it works. But when I change it to weight it does't. I want it in weight so that it looks similar on all devices.

Comment: @KalyanNadimpalli, ok, do you have any specific portion that you want to dedicate to **imageView** so it will remain same irrespective of screen resolution

Answer (score 1):

Take out the scrollview. And reconsider how you are positioning the image, maybe force it towards the top of the view.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        // android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/recPixx"/>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ingredients_list"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```